How to properly create a parent fragment with ViewBinding?
I have around 15 fragments that mostly use the same code, I also have created a BaseFragment for ViewBinding that works, so that I don't need to write that part every time.
However there are other functions that repeat on all fragments, but they utilize the views of each fragment (which is the same on all of them), but I cant for the life of me find how to properly reference them or set them in the BaseFragment.
This is my current BaseFragment:
abstract class BaseFragment<VB : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: VB? = null
    val binding: VB
        get() = _binding!!

    abstract fun inflateBinding(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        attachToRoot: Boolean
    ): VB

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = inflateBinding(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    fun navigateToActivity(activityClass: Class<*>) {
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), activityClass)
        startActivity(intent)
        requireActivity().finish()
    }
}

This is one of the functions that exists on each fragment that I would like to reutilize:
private fun navButtons() {
        binding.btnExit.setOnClickListener {
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            if (currentTime - lastExitButtonClickTime < 2000) {
       
                navigateToActivity(IntroTreasurehuntersActivity::class.java)
            } else {
         
                Toast.makeText(context, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                lastExitButtonClickTime = currentTime
            }
        }
    }

And just in case this is how I do the viewbinding on each of them, which im pretty sure can be much better as well:
class Treasurehuntersq2Fragment : BaseFragment<FragmentTreasurehuntersq2Binding>() {

    override fun inflateBinding(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        attachToRoot: Boolean
    ): FragmentTreasurehuntersq2Binding {
        return FragmentTreasurehuntersq2Binding.inflate(inflater, container, attachToRoot)
    }

Now, If I simple copy that function over to the BaseFragment, of course it doesnt work, because the view button "btnExit" does not exist there. Whats the correct way to do this?

do not use views in BaseFrament keep them limited to child fragment only. Create method to handle the logic in base fragment and call it from child fragment. If any method which is not being re-used there is no point of having it in base class . Read about SOLID principles. you can have separate Base Fragments for different modules as well..

you can make extention functions for those which is repeatedly being used.

I think BaseFragments are a really bad idea if you can avoid it. See the links in this answer for the reasons. You can create all of the functionality you have above using a property delegate and an extension function.

Here’s how you can replace all that view binding code with a delegate. https://zhuinden.medium.com/simple-one-liner-viewbinding-in-fragments-and-activities-with-kotlin-961430c6c07c

Thank you, I was unaware of delegation, I completely agree with the links of the other answer on why this is a nightmare, I was already running onto those issues. Delegates will suit me better

For the ViewBinding Part , you can declare a protected binding property in the baseFragment and let each childFragment to initialize it.
For handling Navigation Event , you can consider using a SharedViewModel between all the fragments, such that any events will be sent from the fragments to the viewModel, and observe those events from the BaseFragment and handle them accordingly, here's an example solution.
abstract class BaseFragment<VB : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

  protected lateinit var binding: VB

 override fun onViewCreated(
    view: View,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
) {
       observeNavigationState()
 }
 
 private fun observeNavigationState(){
     viewModel.NavigateToIntroTreasurehuntersActivity.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { NavigateToIntroTreasurehuntersState -> ->
        if (NavigateToIntroTreasurehuntersState) {  // true i.e naviagtion is started
            val intent = Intent(
                requireActivity(),
                IntroTreasurehuntersActivity::class.java
            )   
            startActivity(intent)  
            requireActivity().finish()  


            viewModel.onNavigateToIntroTreasurehuntersActivityFinished()
        }
    }
 }

 

}
class Treasurehuntersq2Fragment:BaseFragment() {
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {  

    binding = FragmentTreasurehuntersq2Binding.inflate(inflater)  

    return binding.root
}
 
  override fun onViewCreated(
    view: View,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
) {
      setListeners()
  }
  private fun setListeners(){
      binding.btnExit.setOnClickListener {
        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (currentTime - lastExitButtonClickTime < 2000) {
  
            viewModel.onNavigateToIntroTreasurehuntersActivityStarted()
        } else {
     
            Toast.makeText(context, "Press again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            lastExitButtonClickTime = currentTime
        }
    }
  }

}
